# Android exception reporting, Method not found

Tags: android

How do I start to investigate the reported excpetion error as listed bellow?
Im struggling to replicate the issue, and unsure of which method it is referring to.
EDIT user has asked for the onCreate method, this method registers two custom broadcast receivers, One that fires when the connection to the server changes state, the other when a new message is received from the server.
The next code block inflates an xml file used to populate the navigation menu, 5 items with overflow items appearing in a list view popup.

ON CREATE CODE

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); //null

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
            new IntentFilter("CONNECTION_CHANGE_EVENT"));
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(myFSActionReceiver = new FSActionReceiver(this),
            new IntentFilter(FSActionReceiver.action));


    myToolbar = findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

//INFALTE MENU XML AND ADD FIRST 4 ITEMS TO NAVIGATION BAR, ADD "MORE" BUTTON TO MENU BAR
//REMAINING ITEMS IN ARRAY WILL BE DISPLAYED IN "MORE" LIST
    bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            (new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    NavigationItemSelected(item);
                    return true;
                }
            });
    if(bottomNavigationView  != null){
        ArrayList<Pair<Long, MenuItem>> mItemArray = new ArrayList<>();
        Menu menu = new MenuBuilder(this);
        new MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.navigation, menu);

        for(int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++){
            mItemArray.add(new Pair<>((long) i, menu.getItem(i)));
        }
        for (int i = 0 ;i < Math.min(mItemArray.size(),4); i++) {
            MenuItem mItem = mItemArray.get(i).second;
            bottomNavigationView.getMenu().add(mItem.getGroupId(),mItem.getItemId(),mItem.getOrder(),mItem.getTitle()).setIcon(mItem.getIcon());
        }
        MenuItem mItem = mItemArray.get(mItemArray.size()-1).second; //get last item == Menu More
        bottomNavigationView.getMenu().add(mItem.getGroupId(),mItem.getItemId(),mItem.getOrder(),mItem.getTitle()).setIcon(mItem.getIcon());

    }
}
```

ERROR MESSAGE

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:    
java.lang.RuntimeException:     
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3117)    
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3260)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:108)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:68)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1957)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7072)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)     
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)     
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:964)
Caused by: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException:     
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.a (Fragment.java:66)     
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate (FragmentContainer.java)
  or                                        .onFindViewById (FragmentContainer.java)     
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$6.instantiate (FragmentManagerImpl.java)     
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentState.instantiate (FragmentState.java)     
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreSaveState (FragmentManagerImpl.java)     
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.restoreSaveState (FragmentController.java)     
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate (FragmentActivity.java)     
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate (AppCompatActivity.java:10)     
  at uk.co.matthewgroberts.fs1024.core.Main_tab_fragment_host.onCreate (Main_tab_fragment_host.java)     
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7327)     
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7318)     
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1275)     
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3097)     
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3260)     
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:78)     
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:108)     
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:68)     
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1957)     
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)     
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)     
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7072)     
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)     
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)     
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:964)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:      
  at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0 (Class.java:2328)
  at java.lang.Class.getConstructor (Class.java:1725)     
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.a (Fragment.java:15)     
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate (FragmentContainer.java)
  or                                        .onFindViewById (FragmentContainer.java)     
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$6.instantiate (FragmentManagerImpl.java)     
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentState.instantiate (FragmentState.java)     
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreSaveState (FragmentManagerImpl.java)     
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.restoreSaveState (FragmentController.java)     
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate (FragmentActivity.java)     
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate (AppCompatActivity.java:10)     
  at uk.co.matthewgroberts.fs1024.core.Main_tab_fragment_host.onCreate (Main_tab_fragment_host.java)     
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7327)     
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7318)     
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1275)     
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3097)     
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3260)     
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:78)     
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:108)     
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:68)     
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1957)     
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)     
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)     
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7072)     
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)     
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)     
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:964)
```

Comment: The issue is here: at `uk.co.matthewgroberts.fs1024.core.Main_tab_fragment_host.onCreate (Main_tab_fragment_host.java)`. Post your code.

Comment: Code added and short description

Comment: The code you have posted seems Activity, please post code of `Main_tab_fragment_host.java`

Comment: correct, 
     public class Main_tab_fragment_host extends AppCompatActivity implements FSActionReceiver.DataReceived {

Answer (score 0):

Using Java, you can get a NoSuchMethodException when you're using reflection and try to dynamically use a method on a class, and the method does not actually exist.